# Does OracleDB support transaction time?

Tags: oracle12c, temporal-tables

I know that OracleDB supports Valid Time, but does it also support Transaction Time(system-time, application-time)?
Example of attributes that work in sql:

```
sys_start TIMESTAMP(9) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,

sys_end TIMESTAMP(9) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody else will have the same questions: 
-OracleDB supports Valid Time but not Transaction Time.